# CSS: Background Image is zoomed in on mobile & tablet, Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, background

I've some trouble with a parallax background image on mobile. When it's displayed on mobile the image is zoomed right in so I cannot see what it is, it doesn't matter if I use it in landscape or portrait. The same problem occurs also on tablet.

I tried it with `background-size: 100% auto;` now you can see it, but it's just plain ugly. 
Also tried `background-size: contain;` but that also didn't do the job and messed up the desktop view too. 
Also the parallax function isn't working on mobile either way but that doesn't matter to me.

The same problem occurs also on tablet.

[Here's what you see on mobile, when I use `background-size: cover;`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WWTP.jpg)

[Here's what you see on mobile, when I use `background-size: 100% auto;`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv8KJ.jpg)

```css
.intro {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #111;
  min-height: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<section id="intro" style="background-image: url('img/background.jpg'); no-repeat;" class="intro">
```

I'm thankful for any help

P.S. i'm new here, so I hope I asked the right way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-size:cover` would be the right way to go in your case.

The reason it's zoomed in is because `background-size: cover` tries to fill the **full viewport** (which you defined with `height:100%` and `width:100%`). Your image is just not optimized for mobile phones. I bet if you hold your Phone in landscape mode it would look nice. This is because your image has a higher width than height.

I'd suggest using a second image which you then use on mobile devices. You can use a basic image editing tool such as paint, or paint.net to cut out a piece of your image that will work on your mobile phone.

Comment: Sadly, and oddly enough it looks the same in landscape mode… but I will try the secondary image for mobile devices. Thank you!

Comment: Long overdue update: I've solved it with the <picture> tag and 2 different image sizes.